# How does one build MiKTeX on Windows?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, windows, privacy

I want to build MiKTeX (pdflatex specifically) to resolve [this](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/pdftex/2007-August/007290.html) privacy issue with pdflatex by applying [this](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=pdftex&revision=223) change.

I followed [this](http://miktex.org/howto/build-win) howto.

On a new Windows 7 SP1 (32-bit) install I installed:

- CMake (cmake-2.8.12.2-win32-x86.exe)
- Visual Studio C++ 2008 with SP1 (VS2008ExpressWithSP1ENUX1504728.iso)
- Cygwin (default with bison, flex and diffutil)
- ActivePerl (ActivePerl-5.20.1.2000-MSWin32-x86-64int-298557.msi)
- libxslt (libxslt-1.1.26.win32.zip)
- MiKTeX basic with 'install missing packages on-the-fly' (basic-miktex-2.9.5105.exe)
- HTML Help Workshop
- Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 (6.0.6001.18000.367-KRMSDK_EN.iso)

  - with only the Windows Headers and Libraries and Windows Development Tools selected
- ImageMagick (ImageMagick-6.9.0-0-Q16-x86-dll.exe)

To Windows' `PATH` I appended:

```
;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\libxslt-1.1.26.win32\bin;C:\Program Files\HTML Help Workshop
```

I extracted the MiKTeX source (miktex-2.9.4106.tar.bz2) to `C:\miktex`

In `C:\miktex\CMakeLists.txt` I set `NO_GUI = TRUE`

I launched the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt and entered the following:

```
cd \miktex
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"
nmake
```

Building stopped with the following:

```
[ 15%] Building C object Libraries/3rd/obsdcompat/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-obsdcompat.dir/bsd-asprintf.c.obj
bsd-asprintf.c
c:\miktex\libraries\3rd\obsdcompat\defines.h(91) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'u_int8_t'
c:\miktex\libraries\3rd\obsdcompat\defines.h(91) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
c:\miktex\libraries\3rd\obsdcompat\defines.h(92) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'u_int16_t'
c:\miktex\libraries\3rd\obsdcompat\defines.h(92) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
c:\miktex\libraries\3rd\obsdcompat\defines.h(93) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'u_int32_t'
c:\miktex\libraries\3rd\obsdcompat\defines.h(93) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I was able to work around this and subsequent errors, but after each workaround building again stopped with further errors unrelated to the workarounds.
I eventually gave up suspecting there must be something wrong with my build environment or the way I was using it (hence the detail), but I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: I think 'ask Christian Schenk' might be the only realistic answer here: it's hard to imagine that anyone else builds MiKTeX from the sources.

Comment: Doesn't pdfTeX now include that patch? (Although I can't figure out how to use `\pdfsuppressptexinfo`...)

Comment: @cfr: As far as I can tell, the patch is in 1.50, but is not in 1.40.x. MiKTeX still uses 1.40.x. The patch is described [here](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/pdftex/2007-August/007297.html). Also, compare (in [the repository](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/browser.php?group_id=23)) pdftoepdf.cc in trunk to that in the stable branch and those with the 1.40.x tags.

Answer (score 2):

Don't build in the source directory.

Historical:

> Patching `pdftex.web` and `pdftoepdf.cc` in `Programs\TeXAndFriends\pdftex` as necessary (for example, search those files for `.Fullbanner` and `.FileName` respectively) prior to building will result in MiKTeX pdftex binaries that do not add PDF metadata/properties not explicitly specified.